# Null Exception while loading my file to listbox.

Tags: vb.net

I have a problem. I'm trying to load data to listbox , but when I click start I get an unhandled exception that states values cannot be null. I've bolded where the issue is.

I'm trying to create a library database, and would really appreciate if someone could help me fix this issue. Thanks!

Public Class  frmLibrary

```
Structure BookData
    Dim Title As String
    Dim Author As String
    Dim ISBN As Integer
    Dim YearPublished As Integer
End Structure
Dim bookinfo() As BookData   'Array 


Private Sub frmLibrary_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim bookfiles() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines("LibraryDatabase.txt")
    Dim n As Integer = bookfiles.Count - 1
    ReDim bookinfo(n)
    Dim line As String
    Dim books() As String   'books are the parts

    'use the split methods to assign values to the members of the structure variable. 

    For i As Integer = 0 To n  ---**>Why is this value null???????**
        line = bookfiles(i)
        books = line.Split(","c)            '
        bookinfo(i).Title = books(0)
        bookinfo(i).Author = books(1)
        bookinfo(i).ISBN = books(2)
        bookinfo(i).YearPublished = books(3)


    Next

    Dim query = From book In bookinfo
                Select book.Title, book.Author, book.ISBN, book.YearPublished
    DGVBookInfo.DataSource = query.ToList

    DGVBookInfo.Columns("Title").HeaderText = "Title"
    DGVBookInfo.Columns("Author").HeaderText = "Author"
    DGVBookInfo.Columns("ISBN").HeaderText = "ISBN"
    DGVBookInfo.Columns("Year Published").HeaderText = "Year Published"
    DGVBookInfo.AutoResizeColumns()


    DGVBookInfo.RowHeadersVisible = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you sure there is data loaded into `bookfiles()` if it cant read any lines then n won't be able to get any `.Count` value. Also I would recommend using `.Length` as `.Count` is reserved for IEnumerable

Comment: The form_load buries exceptions for most cases. Wrap the line where you fill bookfiles() in a Try...Catch and display the exception in the catch to see what is actually happening.

Comment: Err I don't think `i` or `n` can be null because they are value types, not reference types.